# React doesn't have the same execution order when calling a component as a function rather than using it as a tag?

Tags: reactjs

I was just doing some experimentation and I noticed if I have:

```
const Component1 = () => {
  console.log("Component1");
  return <div>Component1</div>;
};
const Component2 = () => {
  console.log("Component2");

  return <div>Component2</div>;
};
```

Now when using the components like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Component1 />
      {Component2()}

      <button onClick={setState.bind(null, !state)}>Change State</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I noticed that in console.log component2 appears before component1 even tho they are rendered in the correct order, why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSX elements are syntax sugar for `React.createElement`. `React.createElement` does not run the components inside it immediately:

```js
const TheComponent = () => {
  console.log('component being created');
};
React.createElement(TheComponent);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Rather, it waits for the elements to be *rendered*.

When you do

```
<Component1 />
{Component2()}
```

You call `Component2` immediately, but since the rendering doesn't occur instantaneously - it occurs a little bit of time later - `Component1` takes a bit of time to log.

Note that you should never use

```
{Component2()}
```

when rendering an element - always use JSX syntax or `React.createElement`, as React expects you to do.

Comment: I just tried using useState() inside Component2() and it worked, what do you mean:  you can't use certain React-specific helpers, like hooks?

Comment: Oop, you're right. I remember calling components as if they were standard functions causes problems in a number of cases, I thought hooks were one, but they seem to work.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, you're question has mainly two problems.

Comment: The first one is the code snippet. All code snippets should run without errors. But yours has code snippet errors. https://codesandbox.io/s/67944280-answer-error-nwvit

Comment: The second one is the explanation. The exact reason for appearing the console.log earlier is that calling the component as a function is much faster than the normal JSX declaration.  Also, it's not a malpractice like you describe. Resource - https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f

Comment: *Note* - **you're question** should be changed as **your answer** in my first comment here.

Comment: @Yushan My snippet does not render the `TheComponent` - it only calls `createElement` on the component. Nothing logs - this is sufficient to demonstrate that `TheComponent` function does not run when `createElement` is called on it. That was the only purpose of the snippet. Yes, of course in a real component, you'd return something at the end, but the function doesn't run at all here, which is all I was trying to show.

Comment: That syntax is not correct @CertainPerformance. You can't add code snippets with errors. If you want to just explain something then add that like others. Also, do a proper research before making statements like **Note that you should never use**.

Comment: @Yushan The code snippet is not intended to be a full-fledged component one would use in real code, which should be blindingly obvious to anyone - it's just a demonstration of a particular faucet of React. Of course in a real app you'd return something at the end, but the purpose of the snippet is not to make something functional, but to prove a point - which it does.

Comment: yeah, it can easily be recognized by developers like us who had an experience with React. But newcomers will not recognize that at first sight. We have to answer questions by considering the everyone in the community. So just be careful.

Comment: @BerserkGuts React expects hooks to be called in the same order every time a component is rendered, so if you were to use hooks in one of these "components" and conditionally include the "component", it would crash the app. [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-night-8e1zp) It's a tremendously bad idea to combine hooks with this approach since you're essentially using the hooks in the middle of the return statement, so CertainPerformance was right to advise caution about them.

Comment: @JLRishe, **Note that you should never use** means it's a malpractice. If you read the article, you can see that it can be used in real-life projects under certain circumstances.

Comment: @JLRishe, **it’s not a tremendously bad idea**. It just has some drawbacks. You can use them with stateless functional components perfectly. Check working version with hooks. https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-pasteur-n9kzt?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score -1):

The reason for appearing the console.log earlier is that calling the component as a function is much faster than the normal JSX declaration. Research shows it's 45% faster.

Also, it's not a malpractice. It is most suitable with stateless functional components.

Resource - https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f

Let me know if you need further support.

Comment: Follow up, why wouldn't it be better to call all components as a function instead as JSX declaration?

Comment: Class components must extend from React knw. But functional components don't have a requirement like that. So we can easily execute them like native JavaScript functions.

Comment: If you call a synchronous function, its body will execute immediately and complete before anything else can run. OP's observation has nothing to do with one approach being more efficient than another. And if you call a component function directly, you're not actually using a component at all but rather just calling an ordinary function. That's an important distinction and affects the way hooks work, for example.

Comment: Discussion related to hooks already had in the previous answer. Check the comments section in the previous answer. Do a proper research before making a statement @JLRishe.

Comment: I made a comment about _your_ answer because there is an issue with it. The very short mention of hooks under the other answer were by no means comprehensive. If you use hooks in a conditionally included "component" with the approach you're recommending, it will crash the app: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-night-8e1zp Also, your comment on the other answer about the timing of the console.log is wrong. CertainPerformance's explanation is correct.

Comment: @Yushan Yes, why do you ask?

Comment: @JLRishe, [Your codesandsbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-night-8e1zp) has a stateful functional component. But in my answer I also emphasize that it is mostly suitable for stateless functional components.
We cannot tell that hooks don’t support completely. But there can be some drawbacks. That’s why I mention like that in my answer. Working version with hooks https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-pasteur-n9kzt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Yushan The same issue can be observed with essentially _any_ hook, and if you don't like my example with `useState`, here is one with `useMemo`: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-benz-edi17. I'm _not_ saying that this approach is completely without merit, but what I am saying is that it's important to make the distinction that you're not _actually_ using a component here so one can't expect it to behave like one, and it's not a good idea to invoke hooks in the middle of your `return` statement, which someone could do without realizing it if they use this approach.